# int too big to convert in python

Tags: python, dataframe, int, timedelta

I have a calculated 'duration' value from a simulated data. This is nothing but the 'hours' value calculated.  I have written the below code:

```
Duration = 16571835.2920344
Dyn_ETA = pd.Timedelta(hours=Duration)
Dyn_ETA1 = Dyn_ETA.total_seconds()
hours = Dyn_ETA1/3600
result_Dyn = '{0:02.0f}:{1:02.0f}'.format(*divmod(hours * 60, 60))
```

but I am getting below error:

```
OverflowError: int too big to convert 
for
Dyn_ETA = pd.Timedelta(hours=Duration)
```

I wont get this 'duration' value in real time data. But as a safety measure, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Pure Python is fine with arbitrary size integers. Dataframes are not. Use the `datetime` library!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong tool here. `pd.Timedelta` handles durations as an `int64` values of nano seconds. This gives more or less a maximum of 5124095 hours (roughly 584 years).

Your initial duration is close to twice that maximum and cannot be expressed that way. Full stop.

But you do not need it:

```
hour = Duration # taking the total_seconds() from the Timedelta in hour divided by 3600 is a no-op
result_Dyn = '{0:02.0f}:{1:02.0f}'.format(*divmod(hours * 60, 60))
```