# Dataframe save into excel using xlwings

Tags: python, openpyxl, win32com, xlwings

While i am saving my dataframe into excel using xlwings i am getting below error.

[image]

Below is my code .

```
app = xw.App()
app.display_alerts = False

#Template Open
wb = xw.Book(template)
sht = wb.sheets["Flash"]
sht.range('A2').options(index=False,header=False).value = df #copy the dataframes
wb.api.RefreshAll()
wb.save(xl)
wb.close()
app.quit()
xw.apps
```

Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RAVINDRA.K\OneDrive - KPK FASERV INDIA PVT LTD\My Projects\IMEi\IMEI FLASH WH WISE.py", line 441, in <module>
    sht.range('A2').options(index=False,header=False).value = df #copy the dataframes
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1803, in value
    conversion.write(data, self, self._options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\__init__.py", line 48, in write
    pipeline(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\framework.py", line 66, in __call__
    stage(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 74, in __call__
    self._write_value(ctx.range, ctx.value, scalar)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 62, in _write_value
    rng.raw_value = value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1399, in raw_value
    self.impl.raw_value = data
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 808, in raw_value
    self.xl.Value = data
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 103, in __setattr__
    return setattr(self._inner, key, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 482, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

Comment: The edit on your question was to reformat the traceback as code so this it could be read easier. In the current text format it is difficult to delineate the lines. When posting tracebacks please post as text and format as code for readability.

Comment: I'm not sure what data you are using, but perhaps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61770918/int-too-big-to-convert-in-python) will help, if you are using time data.

Comment: It would be nice to describe your data and environment. What is your office version? What is the data types in `df`? How big is your data frame? Can you save some part of `df` in excel? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert to a `pd.DataFrame`

```
sht.range('A2').options(convert=pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False).value = df #copy the dataframes
```